# What the best way for updating GridView in Yii2 with dropDownList?

Tags: ajax, gridview, yii2, pjax

I have stock GridView and i wanna update it with custom dropdown list.
Now i use next code:

```
<? Pjax::begin(); ?>
   //place for dropDownList
   <?= GridView::widget([
                            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                            'showFooter' => TRUE,
                            'columns' => $grid_columns,                         

                        ]); ?>
<? Pjax::end(); ?>
```

and I wanna select some "Month" and "Year" from dropDown and send that data through Pjax. What construction of routing is best?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/)

When you generate an index view with gii, it actually already builds a template for a search form.

Hope it helps!